# Querying master.dbo.syslockinfo much slower on new Sql Server machine

Tags: sql-server, performance, locking

After changing the machine running SQL Server 2019 Standard to a new one (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz, 128GB RAM, SAS SSD RAID10), I noticed a very significant drop in the performance of the ERP application whose database is located on this server.

After analysis using SQL Profiler, it turned out that during operation the application repeatedly queries the system table master.dbo.syslockinfo, e.g.:

```
SELECT rsc_objid FROM master.dbo.syslockinfo
WHERE rsc_type=5 AND object_name(rsc_objid)='Warehouse'
```

Such a (simple) query (even without WHERE clause) is performed in approximately 300 ms, but due to their number (sometimes over 200 during one operation in the application), this adds up to a significant increase in the operation time.

On the old server (Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM), the same query is performed in approximately 30ms.

Similar execution times (ten times faster on old machine) appear for querying the master.sys.dm_tran_locks system view:

```
select * from master.sys.dm_tran_locks
```

Therefore, I suspect that the reason lies somewhere in the Sql Server locking mechanism - but I cannot determine it.

After checking the execution time of the above queries on several other servers (of course, queries executed on an idle server), I only see a relationship between the amount of RAM and the execution time: the more RAM on the server, the slower the queries are executed.

I read that Sql Server Lock Manager creates a lock hash table with the number of slots depending on the physical memory of the server. However, I don't know if this can affect performance or if the number of slots can be controlled.

I will add that changing the 'locks' parameter of Sql Server (e.g. from 0 to 5000) also does not bring any improvement.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the application's source code, so changing this lock table query is not possible.

Have you encountered a similar problem? Can you suggest an idea on how to improve the speed of queries to master.dbo.syslockinfo and master.sys.dm_tran_locks?

Comment: This is going to be localized factors, it seems. What are the wait stats for the session? Do you have an etw trace on cpu? if not do that. I am highly suspect that this is an issue with the lock manager. Not being mean here, but a E5-2667 was "new" in 2016, it's been 7 years and *multiple* architectures since then. I wouldn't call an E5-2667 "fast" by any definition in today's hardware scape.